# Ways to query Facebook Graph "do I like x?"

Tags: facebook, graph, fbml, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api

I'm setting up my app to basically do what the FBML 'like' button does: like, unlike and show like count, for objects from the user's "me/home" stream.
I have no problem doing any of the above functions, but I'm having a very tough time getting the api to tell me if the user likes the thing already (so I can set the button to 'unlike'). The graph api is telling me I'm not allowed to search user's likes. Is there an FQL solution?

Thanks

Comment: This FQL query gives me a likes[user_likes] value of 1 if I like something. It seems to work, but I haven't tested it much. "SELECT post_id, likes FROM stream WHERE post_id = '[THE_POST_ID]"

Answer (score 0):

There is [`like`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like) table where you can check through FQL if someone likes something.